# Change logo on scroll Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My question is how to change logo when page scrolls. I've did research on Stack Overflow and couldn't find a solution. None of the codes brought errors I just couldn't get them to work.

Below is the coding of my website HTML, CSS, and JavaScript of what I'm trying to fix. My HTML follows:

```
<body id="page-top">
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><div class="pull-left"><img class="top-logo" src="img/jtorbiklogo1.png"></a></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-custom">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#web">Web Design</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#graphic">Graphic Design</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The CSS for this code is boostrap.min.css and my own custom CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.top-logo {
width: 600px;
height: 100%;
max-height:132px;
min-height:132px;
margin-top: -58px;
margin-left: -180px;
}
```

The reason it's under my 992px width is that I only want this to happen for any device over 992. Also I have different logo sizes as page shrinks. I want to add JavaScript to change the logo in the navbar once the page scrolls. I found a JavaScript code that I think would work but needs to be tweaked.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $('#custom-nav').addClass('affix');
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','newImage.jpg'); //change src
} else {
    $('#custom-nav').removeClass('affix');
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','OldImage.jpg')
}   
});
```

Comment: It looks to me like your code is working. Have a look at this. [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/QMvVVa)

Comment: I see it works on copdepen but when I try to implement into my website navbar it doesn't respond. That's were I'm stuck. I tried everything. Maybe you can take a look at it. @DanKreiger

Comment: If it's working with just the code you provided, but not on your website, there is probably more code somewhere that's causing the problem. My first guess would be additional CSS that's overriding what you have provided here.

Check the inspector in your browser to see if all of the CSS is getting applied, and make sure it's not overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say thank you to @DanKreiger & @katniss.everbean for there help. I've gotten it to work by following steps katniss given me. The problem was my jquery link was at bottom and this was causing a define problem which caused the script to not respond. I'm new to Stack Overflow. I don't know if I can give points yet. I'll mark as solved and yet again, thank you both for your help!